# Enforce the highest version from among several conflicting transitive dependencies in gradle

Tags: gradle, grails

I work on a large project with multiple services and libraries, mostly in **`grails`**, with **`gradle`** builder. I'm trying to update a library (say **`logback`**) for security reasons.

I already updated it in one of our libraries (say **`our-logger`**), like so:

```
#our-logger/build.gradle
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
    ...
}
```

when I update a service (say **`our-service`**) to use the new version of `our-logger` i get logback included from other libraries, and gradle chooses the **lower** version coming through `cobertura` and some other dependencies, instead of the higher version coming through `our-logger`.

```
#our-service/build.gradle
...
apply plugin: 'cobertura'
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'our-logger:9.99' # safe now with logback-1.2.3
    ...
}
```

```
~/our-service $ ./gradlew dependencies
...

cobertura
\--- net.sourceforge.cobertura:cobertura:2.1.1
     +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.13 -> 1.1.11
     |    \--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.11
...
compile - Dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'implementation ' instead).
+--- org.grails:grails-dependencies:3.3.8
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.4.2.RELEASE -> 1.5.15.RELEASE
|    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.11
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.11
...
+--- our-logger:9.99
|    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3 -> 1.1.11 (*)
```

How do I enforce `logback-1.2.3` without explicitly declaring it in all services?

Answer (score 1):

The gradle docs file this under Advanced Dependency Management.  You should be able to satisfy your goal using  `excludes`.  There are other ways too [Gradle Docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html)

```
compile(“some:other:dependency”) {
    exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
}
```

Comment: ```    compile ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.5.18.RELEASE') {
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'  
    } 
```
did not help. now the version 1.1.11 is apparently coming from nowhere, but still overriding my version...

Comment: You might try naming the logback you want as an implementation dependency in this project.  This is also discussed in the link as a way to select a version when there are conflicts. `implementation('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3')`